# Django - Videos files are not loading in view

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views

I have a video_post model for a blog I'm creating. The video files are saved properly and appear in the designated folder as planned. However, when I load the video_details page in order to view them, the html video tag just loads forever. I checked the console and it does not say that the file cannot be found, it just seems to never load. I'll post my model, view, and display below, I believe more than likely it's a video file type issue or an html issue, but I'm lost at this point:

```
Model:
class VideoPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/')
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

```
View:
def video_detail(request, id):
    video = VideoPost.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {
        'title': 'LIFT Church - Video Sermen',
        'video': video
    }

    return render(request, 'sermen-video.html', context)
```

```
View:
<video autoplay controls>
    <source src="{{ video.post_video.url }}" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="{{ video.post_video.url }}" type="video/ogv">
    <source src="{{ video.post_video.url }}" type="video/ogg">
    Video type invalid or not supported...
  </video>
```

Comment: Try to "view source" of the rendered page, do you see the video url? Can you access the file via this url directly?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was actually Ubuntu 16.04 Firefox. My version of Firefox did not support mp4 video types and I needed to update in order for things to work properly. Posting this in case anyone else has this issue.